# How to get uploaded file name from temp folder in php?

Tags: php, html, forms, apache2

I'm using method="GET" in my HTML form. Is there any way to get name of temporary file from temp folder(in Linux) and move it to some self-made folder? I have tried $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] but it doesn't work with get method. To fetch values from query string I've used $_GET method. But its not getting temp file name.

Comment: Read the manual on [files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Comment: I've use $_FILES but its not showing any value.

Comment: From the manual: _$_FILES An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method._ It's working with POST in your form, not with GET

Comment: I am using GET and i can fetch values from string so far. But cant read temp file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File uploads are not possible with the GET method, so you have to use the POST method.

This is *not* a PHP issue. [RFC 1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) specifies the form enctype "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" when sending files. But setting an enctype is only possible when you use POST. Additionally files can be very big, so the URL's query string would be too long.

In fact, your browser will never send any file to the server if you use GET. It treats the file input field as a normal text field and sends the file's name.

Comment: OK. If i use post method then is there any way to fetch values from query string? Because when i used POST method i wasn't able to do that.

Comment: If they are really sent in the query string you can also access them via $_GET['name']. If you changed the form type to POST and you submit  text inputs this way, they are no longer available in $_GET but in $_POST. You could alsy try $_REQUEST['name'] if you are not sure.

Comment: If I am not sure about what??

Comment: If you are not sure if a field is in the query string ($_GET) or in the request body ($_POST).Without a code example it's really hard to guess how everything looks like and what you want to do. Could you provide additional infos in the question?

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I have used POST method in my HTML form. And fetched elements through $_POST. It worked :)!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form? If don't, there is no data in $_FILES

However, it's recommended to use POST for inserting and GET for fetching data

Comment: I know its better to use post but as i have to read query string which is done through $_GET. So thats why I'm using GET .

Comment: Why do you need GET method in your form for fetching your data? You can fetch your query string using GET and send your data using POST I think you don't need form for retrieve data